# Java for loop - (i * 16) evaluating to 0 for all values of i

Tags: java, for-loop, slick2d

Probably missing something basic, but I have a for-loop in my program that's supposed to iterate over an array (`lines[]`) and draw them onscreen (using LWJGL/Slick).
Instead of the lines being shown on separate lines (at `(i*16 + 7, 5)`), they all appear at `(7, 5)`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  if(lines[i] != null) {
    f.drawString((i * 16) + 7, 5, lines[i]);
  }
}
```

I have seen answers on other questions suggesting to define a final variable in the loop to avoid the value being changed before the called function uses it. So I have changed the code to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  if(lines[i] != null) {
    final int i2 = i;
    f.drawString((i2 * 16) + 7, 5, lines[i]);
  }
}
```

But it doesn't fix it (didn't really expect it to, as I'm not getting stuck on the last value of i and Slick shouldn't be storing the value of i, but tried it to make sure).

---

The header of drawString is as follows:

```
public void drawString(float x, float y, String whatchars)
```

Comment: (keep in mind) If i == 0, i * 16 == 0 too.

Comment: I think you may have your arguments in the wrong order. What kind of object is `f` (Fixed wrong object name)

Comment: For the first iteration, yes, but when i increases to 1 in the next iteration, 1*16 seems to be evaluated to 0 too.

Comment: Don't know the arguments, but could it be you're drawing each new object with a horizontal shift instead of a vertical shift?

Comment: r? I don't have an r, do you mean f? TrueTypeFont, the method is public void drawString(float x, float y, String whatchars)

Comment: Are you using an IDE to code? Can you debug the code and set a breakpoint to watch the variables there? EDIT: Also keep in mind, if you're looking to offset the *LINES* you need to have the (i * 16) constant in the `y` position.

Comment: Also, check your lines[] array. If the only non-null value in the array is at lines[0] that's all you're going to get, is (7,5) for lines drawn.

Comment: @TheCapn, that's it. Said it'd be basic. EDIT: wrong person.

Comment: You do have the horizontal shift instead of the vertical shifting that you want. Try using debug tools to look at the i-value each iteration or adding a println for the value of i.

Comment: Have you done any research, such as printing the values or using an IDE debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess my comment supplied the answer so I'll post for others to help.

The *correct* call is to put the offset in the *y* parameter of the function:

```
f.drawString(7, (i * 16)+5, lines[i]);
```

As the function definition is:

```
public void drawString(float x, float y, String whatchars)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `y` co-ordinate not `x` as below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  if(lines[i] != null) {
   f.drawString(7, (i * 16) +5, lines[i]);
  }
 }
```

This will print the lines from `x = 7` and `y varying from 5 to 20`.